# how to make music21 play a particular music instrument?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, music21

I have trained a neural network that generates music using LSTM. But it always return music from piano only.. I've tried to use instrument.Guitar() method also. It doesn't work. I get piano music only. Why this happens? Any suggestions would be helpful..
This is my code.

```
def convert_to_midi(prediction_output):
   
    offset = 0
    output_notes =[]


    # create note and chord objects based on the values generated by the model
    for pattern in prediction_output:
        notes=[]
        # pattern is a chord
        if ('.' in pattern) or pattern.isdigit():
            notes_in_chord = pattern.split('.')
            for current_note in notes_in_chord:
                
                cn=int(current_note)
                new_note = note.Note(cn)
                #new_note.storedInstrument = instrument.Guitar()
                notes.append(new_note)
                
            new_chord = chord.Chord(notes)
            new_chord.offset = offset
            output_notes.append(instrument.Violin())
            output_notes.append(new_chord)
            
        # pattern is a note
        else:
            
            new_note = note.Note(pattern)
            new_note.offset = offset
            #new_note.storedInstrument = instrument.Guitar()
            output_notes.append(instrument.Violin())
            output_notes.append(new_note)

        # increase offset each iteration so that notes do not stack
        offset += 1
    #midi_stream1=stream.Score()
    #midi_stream1.insert(output_notes)
    #midi_stream = stream.Stream(output_notes)
  
    #midi_stream.write('midi', fp='music11.mid')
    #midi_stream1.write("midi", fp="music15.mid")
    midi_stream = stream.Stream(output_notes)
    midi_stream.write('midi', fp='final_music2.midi')
```

Comment: Your code is generating MIDI files. These only contain information on what notes are being played when; there is no information on instruments. Your problem lies with whatever you are using to play the files.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to change the player that I use to play the files?. I'm currently using Windows Media player to play the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

The `storedInstrument` property has not been promoted to `Note` objects yet, but might happen in future versions of `music21`. For now, try simply inserting an `instrument.Guitar` instance into the `Stream` object at whatever point you need the MIDI program change.